# Windows 2019 IIS On Premise Application Insight Monitor Status

Tags: azure, powershell, iis, appinsights

I am upgrading our IIS Servers to use Windows Server 2019 instead of 2012 R2. We had on our Windows Server 2012 R2 IIS server the Application Insights Monitor Status application on there and then ApplicationInsights.config file for our individual apps. So I have two questions:

1. Does the Application Insights Monitor Status not work on Windows Server 2019? I could install it but when it tries to fetch the latest nuget packages it fails.
2. I started using Microsoft's new method of installing the agent via powershell but we have one web site with multiple virtual apps, and we have different instrument keys for each virtual app. I could not figure out a way to make each virtual app use a different instrument key. It seems like you can only use a different instrument key per site. Is that correct or is there another way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OS support for Application Insights Status Monitor on Server:

1. Windows Server 2008
2. Windows Server 2008 R2
3. Windows Server 2012
4. Windows server 2012 R2
5. Windows Server 2016

Status Monitor is no longer recommended for use, and starting June 1st 2021 this version of Status monitor will not be supported. It has been replaced by the Azure Monitor Application Insights Agent (formerly named Status Monitor v2). For information about it, you can refer to this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/monitor-performance-live-website-now#download).